# Inserting data into my database using a while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I've currently got a while loop running through one database which is selecting the data fine, one of the columns i am displaying an image which when clicked i want to insert the data into a different database.

The if statement im using to insert the data is;

```
if (isset($_POST['acceptloan'])):

$username=$_POST['username'];
$product=$_POST['product'];
$start_loan=$_POST['start_loan'];
$return_loan=$_POST['return_loan'];


$my_iquery="INSERT INTO loans VALUES ('','$username','$product','','','$start_loan','$return_loan','No')";

$iresult= mysqli_query($connection, $my_iquery);

if ($iresult):
            header ('location: homepage.php?confirm=Loan Accepted');
        else :
            echo "<b>This didn`t work, error: </b>";
            echo mysqli_error($connection);
endif;
endif;
```

I've tested this and it works however im not sure how to get my php to run it from my while loop.

My while loop is ;

```
while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):


$requestid          = $myrow["requestid"];
$username           = $myrow["username"];
$product            = $myrow["product"];
$start_loan         = $myrow["start_loan"];
$return_loan        = $myrow["return_loan"];

$table = '<tr>';

    $table.= '<td>'.$requestid.'';
    $table.= '<td>'.$username.'';
    $table.= '<td>'.$product.'';
    $table.= '<td>'.$start_loan.'';
    $table.= '<td>'.$return_loan.'';
    $table.= "<td align='center'><a onClick =\"return confirm('Are You Sure You Want To Accept This Request?')\" href=acceptrequest.php?requestid=$requestid><img src=\"tick2.png\">";
    $table.= "<td><a onClick =\"return confirm('Are You Sure You Want To Reject this Request?')\" href=deleterequest.php?requestid=$requestid><img src=\"delete.png\">";


echo $table;
endwhile;
```

The code in which im referring to is the accept request line - how would I point the code to perfrom the IF statement?

Thanks

Comment: your while loop is fetching data, not inserting. Please be a bit more clear about what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @e4c5 im aware that my while loop is fetching data, that is what its supposed to do. within the loop it is putting the tick2.png image on every row for a specific column. when the image is pressed i want the If statement to be performed so all data from the current row is inserted into the 'loans' database

Comment: that makes things a wee bit clearer, still murky. If I have understood correctly, you need to invest in ajax

Answer (score 0):

In your acceptrequest.php page, check if $_GET['requestid'] is set and then perform your insert query.(make sure you have the correct data in place)

You haven't shown how you have received the data via POST in your first block of code...could have made things clearer.